# Python subprocess shell scripts still runs in background

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am running two python scripts using subprocess one of them still runs.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("python3 script_with_loop.py & python3 scrip_with_io.py", shell=True)
```

script_with_loop still runs in the background.

What is the way to kill both scripts if one of them dies?

Comment: " if one of them dies", if think the more correct way to say this is one of them `finishes its task` or `is done`

Comment: so you want to kill `script_with_loop` after the `script_with_io` is done?

Comment: @alexzander yes that's true... solution with threading and using the statement below worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're basically not using python here, you're using your shell.

`a & b` runs a, disavows it, and runs b. Since you're using the shell, if you wanted to terminate the background task, you'd have to use shell commands to do that.

Of course, since you're using python, there is a better way.

```
with subprocess.Popen(["somecommand"]) as proc:
  try:
    subprocess.run(["othercommand"])
  finally:
    proc.terminate()
```

Looking at your code though - `python3 script_with_loop.py` and `python3 script_with_io.py` - my guess is you'd be better off using the `asyncio` module  because it basically does what the names of those two files are describing.

Answer (score 2):

you should use threading for this sort of thing. try this.

```
import threading

def script_with_loop():
    
    try:
        # script_with_loop.py code goes here
    except:
         _exit()


def script_with_io():
    
    try:
        # script_with_io.py code goes here
    except:
         _exit()


threading.Thread(target=script_with_loop, daemon=True).start()
threading.Thread(target=script_with_io, daemon=True).start()
```